# Windows 8 desktop refreshes every 30secs

Tags: windows, desktop

Desktop blanks every 30 secs or so for a second (icons and wallpaper) except for any active windows.

Windows update had stopped working and I ran the windows troubleshooter to fix the problem. It did but now have this desktop refresh problem.

I have all the latest updates and have used Windows virus checker and spybot to scan the hard drive. nothing found.

Windows 8 Enterprise 32bit
Athlon X2 6000 - 3.1ghz
2 GB ram
Geforce 9800 GTX+OC

Comment: Sounds like a graphic display driver problem.  Install the current driver for your card.  Report all information in the future for instance WHICH update you last installed.

Comment: It seems you lost the browser cookie identifying you as "user194292". Please register an account on the site with the *same email address as you asked the question with*. Then click "flag" just below the question, and request that "user194292" be merged into your new account. Then you'll be able to edit the question to provide additional information.